# how i can access local web or database server remotely without static IP

Tags: php, sql-server, webserver, remote-access

how i can access my local web server or database server access remotely without static ip address, i have desktop database driven app which is saving data in MS SQL server i want to access data on company current site hosted on bluehost, is there any way to access following points

1. MS SQL server remote acces without static IP address
2. Or I will write a web service in PHP connected with MS SQL database sending REST API information to online site how to access local web server without static ip address

Answer (score 4):

1. Get a new [Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com)
2. Install the [Dynamic DNS update software](http://www.noip.com/download?page=win) on the computer hosting the services.
3. On your home internet router, [forward the ports](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) `80` and `3306` to the computer hosting the services.

That's it, you should now be able to connect to the `WebServer` and `MySql` database by pointing your requests to, i.e.:

```
mycomputer.no-ip.me
```

Comment: thank i am checking same solution now port forwarding is left thanks once solution works will up this answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the www.noip.com service. They have a service for people who have an ISP that doesn't provide an static external ip. You can get a hostname, example: yourname.no-ip.org and you run no-ip's client on your pc that will check if your external ip changes. If it does, it will automatically fix the necessary dns changes for your hostname, so the hostname points to your new ip.

Or you got similar providers like dyndns.

EDIT: Don't forget that you might have to port forward the ports for the services you are trying to reach outside of your network. (Examples: www.portforward.com)

Comment: thank i am checking same solution now port forwarding is left thanks once solution works will up this answer