# How to Access Local MySQL Database Remotely without a Public IP

Tags: mysql, remote-access

i would like to know if there is a way of accessing a local MySQL Database remotely without a public IP Address.
I've a local mysql database called "Books", it is running on a local PC here with Internet Access... I'll travel for some days and i wanted to still have access to that database through Internet, but i don't have a public IP address.

I can't simply clone the database to my laptop, because there are some applications that are using this Database on my local network and i've to maintain its consistency.

is there any way or tool that can help accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean _You dont have a public IP Address_

Comment: Maybe using Dynmaic DNS. There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870119/how-i-can-access-local-web-or-database-server-remotely-without-static-ip

Comment: If you have a router or even a model, you do have a  public IP address. But if you dont realise that then the process to allow access to your database is probably going to be to complex for you to achieve

Comment: Maybe you could use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: Thanks @ben Rhys-Lewis ... Pedro Lobito answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a VPN in combination with a dynamic DNS service. If you have a Internet connection, then you have a public IP - but it may need to be port-forwarded appropriately (firewall, router, etc.).